# Exception raised during rendering: 2439228 The following classes could not be found: - Button

Tags: android, eclipse

My application and Eclipse were working fine until I did somes changes of background colors for several buttons. Then the graphical layout does not want to render any more. I get the following message :

Exception raised during rendering: 2439228
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- Button (Change to android.widget.Button, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

I've tried the  3 options given by Eclipe to no avail. I've tried to fix projext, no result.  Somehow, I lost something on the way, but I can't get it back.  Doe anyone have an idea?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/layout_back"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/num_key_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/num_key_height"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttoncle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttoncle"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
        android:background="@color/key_back"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="@color/Dark_Slate_Grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/num_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonmul"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/num_key_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/num_key_height"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
        android:background="@color/key_back"
        android:text="x"
        android:textColor="@color/Dark_Slate_Grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/operator_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Is the XML code appearing; could you paste the code here;

Comment: Yes, the XML code is showing.  I pasted parts of the code.  the rest of code not pasted are also buttons

Comment: You can try to use the full packagename and replace Button with com.android.Button, but I don't see why this should be a Problem, since the namespace import is in your XML

Comment: I found the error : a line of XML code  "android:textStyle="@color/Dark_Slate_Grey"  It should be "bold".  I could not believe that this single line just locked out the whole rendering of the entire layout.  thanks for trying to help me